# Trading View Pine Script for multiple conditions

Tags: pine-script

I'm trying to find out if its possible to receive alerts on TradingView only when three conditions have been met.

Example: Only signal a long when:

- Price closes above Kijun-sen line (Line from Ichimoku)
- Absolute Strength Index Line closes above Absolute Strength Index's MA
- Aroon Up crosses above Aroon down line

Only enter a short when all conditions are reversed...

Is this doable ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it should be doable. I will look into this for you.

Which Absolute Strength Index indicator are you using on TV? I can't find it in the 'Built-ins' indicator category. What is the name of the specific indicator you are using for this? I assume you are using one from the 'Public Library'?

Comment: Wow! Didn’t think I’d get an answer Lol!! Thank you so much!!

I use the “Absolute Strenght Index Oscillator” by Lazy Bear!

Using that along with “Oscar Simple Trend Ichimoku Kijun-Sen” by CapnOscar (settings at 34/5) at first I was only using the regular Kijun-sen... by this one has an additional MA to it for extra confirmation! 

I just added the “SuperTrend” by KivancOzbilgic (Settings ATR Period 10, ATR Multiplier 2) OR just the regular Aroon as previously mentioned